# UIAlertView actions not happening swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

I have a login page in my app. The user enters their username and their password. I have an API that tells me if the username and password are correct and the user's id if they are. If they are not correct it shows a UIAlertView() that asks if you would like to create an account. The view has two buttons. A "No" button which dismisses the view and a "Yes" button which is supposed to contact an API to create the user's account. I have created alert actions before but it will not work with the code I have below. If you wouldn't mind could you please take a look and help me diagnose the problem?

```
//
//  File.swift
//  Reading Logs
//
//  Created by Andrew on 12/8/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Wilson Apps for Education. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class UserLogin {

var loginAlert = UIAlertView()
    var user: String = ""
    var pass: String = ""

    func checkLogin() -> Bool{
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let stat = defaults.valueForKey("loggedIn")
    if(String(stat!) == "0"){
        return false
    }else{
        return true
    }
}


    func logout(){
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.setValue("0", forKey: "loggedIn")
        defaults.setValue("", forKey: "logKey")
        defaults.setValue("0", forKey: "userKey")
    }

    func login(username username: String, password: String, completion: (result: String) -> Void){
        self.user = username
        self.pass = password
        let url = "http://www.wilsonfamily5.org/rlog/checkLogin.php?u=\(username)&p=\(password)"
        let nsUrl = NSURL(string:url)
        let nsUrlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: nsUrl!)
        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(nsUrlRequest){
            (data, response, error) in
            guard
                let data = data,
                let contents = NSString(data:data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                else { return }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                if(contents as String == "0"){
                    self.loginAlert = UIAlertView(title: "No Account Found", message: "We did not find an account matching that criterea. Do you want us to create you an account?", delegate:nil, cancelButtonTitle: "No")
                    self.loginAlert.addButtonWithTitle("Yes")
                    self.loginAlert.show()
                }else{
                    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
                    defaults.setValue(contents as String, forKey: "userKey")
                    defaults.setValue("1", forKey: "loggedIn")
                    completion(result: "1")

                }
            })
            }.resume()
    }

    func register(username: String, password: String){
        let url = "http://www.wilsonfamily5.org/rlog/newAccount.php?u=\(username)&p=\(password)"
        let nsUrl = NSURL(string:url)
        let nsUrlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: nsUrl!)
        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(nsUrlRequest){
            (data, response, error) in
            guard
                let data = data,
                let contents = NSString(data:data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                else { return }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
                defaults.setValue(contents as String, forKey: "userKey")
                defaults.setValue("1", forKey: "loggedIn")
            })
            }.resume()
    }

    func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
        print("ButtonClicked")
        if(buttonIndex == 1){
            print("1ButtonClicked")
            register(user, password: pass)
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: I tested your loginAlert UIAlertView variable and it worked for me properly. Maybe your if statement is not right. Please check what will be the contents String if you give false password and username.

Comment: @GyorgyTrum It is not the if statement because I added a breakpoint there and it still gave me the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step-1**

Add `UIAlertViewDelegate` to your class;

```
class UserLogin, UIAlertViewDelegate {
....
```

**Step-2**

Set delegate and implement "Yes" button `loginAlert` object;

```
self.loginAlert = UIAlertView(title: "No Account Found", message: "We did not find an account matching that criterea. Do you want us to create you an account?", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "No", otherButtonTitles: "Yes")
self.loginAlert.show()
```

Now `clickedButtonAtIndex` function will be triggered.

Answer (score 1):

You should use **UIAlertViewController** instead of **UIAlertView** because

> UIAlertView is deprecated in iOS 9

Here is a code of UIAlertController in Swift and its pretty simple to use.The main thing is that it's Block based and No need to use any delegate

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Default AlertController", message: "A standard alert", preferredStyle: .Alert)

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
            println("you have pressed the Cancel button");
 }
   alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
            println("you have pressed OK button");
 }
   alertController.addAction(OKAction)

  self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

Comment: I can't do that because my application runs on iOS 7 as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Delegate, so you can receive alerts callbacks:

```
 self.loginAlert = UIAlertView(title: "No Account Found", message: "We did not find an account matching that criterea. Do you want us to create you an account?", delegate:self, cancelButtonTitle: "No"
```

Comment: +Taier Now it is giving me a bad access code after I added that

Comment: @AndrewWilson Did it come to alertView: clickedButtonAtIndex?

Comment: If you're using iOS 8 or later, consider using `UIAlertController` instead.. [UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIAlertControllerStyle) `UIAlertView` is deprecated now...

Comment: @Taier No. It did not output "ButtonClicked"

Comment: @AndrewWilson I saw you'r error message, and it looks like you put things inside each other, and now UILabel (root class I guess) is your (self) and on runetime, it did not implement AlertView delegate :(